# Android Hamburger icon is an arrow on 4.x

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've implemented the ActionBarDrawerToggle with the hamburger icon (support library v7), but for some reason the toggle only displays a 'back' arrow on devices not running 5.0 (I have confirmed this for all 4.x versions). Is this normal behaviour?

The arrow looks like this:

[image: The arrow]

Now the arrow icon doesn't change. It's the same when the navigation drawer is pulled out, or when it is in collapsed mode.

This is how I initalize the drawertoggle etc.

```
// drawer toggle
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**

For some clarification. I am using the old regular ActionBar, not the Toolbar. The hamburger icon DOES show on 5.0 devices but not on < 5.0. Should I use the toolbar to fix this problem?

Comment: where have you called the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the hamburger icon this piece of code below is enough

```
Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

it's showing back button because you are using the method `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Check out the official reference [Click here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: See my edit. I am not using the toolbar. I am using the actionbar. The hamburger icon does show up but not on phones pre 5.0

Comment: try changing this `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
` to `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeEnabled(true);
`

Comment: That method isn't available.

Comment: You are using the new library thn it should be there just check or else remove this statement as you already have the method setHomeButtonEnabled set to true

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy the drawable and rename it and use that instead if you want it to be the same on all devices.

Comment: But how would I implement the animation etc.?